# javascript poll php script every 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, php

How do I check a value in a php script for change using javascript?

I would like to do something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
var innitialID = get_file_contents(lastPresentID.php); //get_file_contents(lastPresentID.php);

function myTimeout() {
    var freshestID = get_file_contents(lastPresentID.php);
    if(freshestID != innitialID) {
            location.reload();
        }
  setTimeout(myTimeout, 5000);
}
window.onload = myTimeout;
</script>
```

the php script generates a single integer which is the last ID of a table.

Thanks!

Comment: `get_file_contents` is not a JavaScript function

Comment: What is the get_file_contents function doing? Is it a js function with an ajax call?

Comment: Okay, but do you know how to substitute it for real javascript?
I'd love to learn how to get this done correctly

Comment: You want to look at something called AJAX

Comment: what I am trying to do is call a php script that collects the latest ID of a table in MySQL. When I call that script in the browser, it gives a perfect integer, nothing else, of the latest ID.

Comment: @AshleyMedway, I am trying to limit my learning subjects... I was hoping to get it done in javascript :-(

Comment: @CorCool: AJAX is part of JavaScript. It is also precisely what you're asking us for. Your JavaScript book should cover this; which one are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = doAjax(true);
    setInterval(doAjax, 5000);

    var initialID = -1, freshestID;

    function doAjax(initial) {
      var xmlhttp;
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); // code for IE6, IE5
      }

      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
           if(initial) {
               initialID = xmlhttp.responseText;
           } else {
               freshestID = xmlhttp.responseText;
               if (initialID != freshestID)
                   location.reload();
           }                   
        }
      }

      xmlhttp.open("GET", "lastPresentID.php", true);
      xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

Here we go, updated with ajax calls in there. First sets the initialId variable, then the interval code runs every 5 seconds and update the freshestId variable, and does the comparision.

EDIT: Code is now not duplicated.

Comment: 1. Massive code duplication. 2. Delete your old incorrect answer.

Comment: @AshleyMedway 1. OP is not using any ajax library, so a little duplicated pure javascript code might help him learn something. 2. There are comments on previous answer that might be valuable to understanding this answer. 3. If your not going to be constructive, quit trolling :)

Comment: I am being very constructive, you don't need an AJAX library to write code that is not duplicated. See: http://jsfiddle.net/FDyf8/

Comment: @AshleyMedway - that does not work, your code has no way of knowing which variable it is updating. You just alert them out, but do not set oldvar and newvar, theres no comparision of them. Its back to square one for the OP who was hoping to learn some working JS.

Comment: @Husman I tried this code, at the bottom of my page. Yet is does not work. But this is way more difficult then I had anticipated... wow.

Comment: @Husman I was just showing an idea, but to prove a point. fulling working example. http://jsfiddle.net/FDyf8/2/

Comment: @AshleyMedway Brilliant... But 1. Code isn't modular. 2. Delete your old incorrect comment ;)

Comment: on my Chrome javascript console I get error: Uncaught ReferenceError: innitialID is not defined 
What is this referring to?

Comment: @Husman thanks for this help! There is no way I would have found that. Now I need to dissect that code and try to understand it's functions ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The code below on load will assigns `oldVal`. Then using `setInterval` will update `newVal` every 5 secodns and check if `newVal != oldVal`.

It gets the values from `lastPresentID.php` using [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_intro.asp).

```
var oldVal = 0;
var newVal = 0;

function loadXMLDoc(old) {
    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 ) {
           if(xmlhttp.status == 200){
               if(old)
               {
                   oldVal = xmlhttp.responseText;
               }
               else
               {
                   newVal = xmlhttp.responseText;

                   if(newVal != oldVal)
                       alert("test");
               }                   
           }
           else if(xmlhttp.status == 400) {
              alert('There was an error 400')
           }
           else {
               alert(xmlhttp.status)
           }
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "lastPresentID.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function timeout() {
    loadXMLDoc(false);
}

loadXMLDoc(true);
setInterval(timeout, 5000);
```